# Highcharts , Types of property 'series' are incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I m creating a charts in angular using Highchart ,
but I m getting this error while compiling .
The properties are compatible, but typescript compiler
throws an error. I don't understand why and how to avoid this error.
Any suggestion ?
I m using angular 11

```
 error TS2322: Type '{ chart: { type: string; }; title: { text: string; }; xAxis: { categories: string[]; }; yAxis: { title: { text: string; }; }; series: ({ name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color?: undefined; } | { name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color: string; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
  Types of property 'series' are incompatible.
    Type '({ name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color?: undefined; } | { name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOptionsType[]'.
      Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color?: undefined; } | { name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOptionsType'.
        Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOptionsType'.       
          Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; type: string; color?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'.   
            Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
              Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'XrangePointOptionsObject[]'.
                Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'.

3   [options]="chartOptions"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

  title = 'myHighchart';
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  data = [{

          name: 'ItSolutionStuff.com',
          data: [500, 700, 555, 444, 777, 877, 944, 567, 666, 789, 456, 654],
          type: "spline",
          

       },{      
          name: 'Nicesnippets.com',
          data: [677, 455, 677, 877, 455, 778, 888, 567, 785, 488, 567, 654],
          type: "spline",
           color: '#3183F5'

       }];
 
       chartOptions = {   
    chart: {
      type: "spline"

    },
    title: {
       text: "Monthly Site Visitor"
    },
    xAxis:{
       categories:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    yAxis: {          
       title:{
          text:"Visitors"
       } 
    },
    series: this.data
  };
```

```html
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">

></highcharts-chart>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data is correct, please check how casting to any will work, `chartOptions: any = ...`.

When you want to follow the rules you should not initiate the chart with series predefined like this: `series: this.data`.
You might create a variable for each element of series for example `name`, `data`, `color` etc., or even keep that in the array. However, the whole structure of the series should be defined in the `chartOptions`, otherwise, the chart will trow errors.

```
series: [
  {
    name: this.name1,
    type: "spline",
    data: this.data1
  },
  {
    type: "spline",
    data: this.data2,
    name: "Nicesnippets.com",
    color: "#3183F5"
  }
]
```

You also might always create your own TS interface or extend the existing one.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-dpqftl

Answer (score 1):

```
series:this.data as SeriesOptionsType[]
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`SeriesOptionsType` is just a collection of all series options types, and it doesn't specify `data`. All series options types define `data` specifically for that series type. In your case (spline chart), you should be using `SeriesSplineOptions` instead.